# How to remove all packages from specific repo without dependencies

Tags: linux, command-line, centos, repository, centos6.5

I know following code will remove all package from specific repo.

```
yum remove $(yum list installed | grep rpmforge | awk '{ print $1 }')
```

And following code will remove a package without dependencies.

```
rpm -e --nodeps "php-sqlite2-5.1.6-200705230937"
```

But i don't know how to use together.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try the following command：

```
rpm -e --nodeps `yum list installed | grep rpmforge | awk '{ print $1 }'`
```

Comment: You can also just use `awk` for the search.

E.g. 

`yum list installed | awk '($3 ~ "rpmforge") {print $1}' | xargs rpm -e --nodeps`

Answer (score 46):

Print list of all repositories to get repo id (first column):

```
$ dnf repolist
```

Now remove all packages of selected repo:

```
# dnf repository-packages <repo-id> remove
```

See *repository-packages* section of `dnf` [manual page](http://linuxmanpages.net/manpages/fedora21/man8/dnf.8.html) for details regarding manipulation with all packages in specific repository.

Comment: a note, this will also uninstall any dependencies installed from other repos.

Answer (score 3):

I like using 
    `yum -y autoremove  yum list installed | grep rpmforge | awk '{ print $1 }'`

Comment: `yum -y autoremove $(yum list installed | grep ius | awk '{ print $1 }')`

Comment: For the fyi, when you output yum through a pipe, it doesn't always print entries on a single line. (How flippin' frustrating is that??) If there's a package with a long name that came from the repo you're interested in, it might display the package name on one line, then a newline, then the version and repo columns. That would mean that your grep for the repo name might not catch the associated package name and your command wouldn't work. There's no way to make it work. To see what I'm talking about, do a 'yum list installed | less'.

Answer (score 2):

**Check to Make Sure That You're Erasing Only What You Want To**

```
dnf list installed | grep package_name.i686 | awk '{ print $1 }' | less
```

**Actually Do The Removing**

```
sudo rpm -e --nodeps `dnf list installed | grep package_name.i686 | awk '{ print $1 }'`
```

Answer (score 0):

**This one works with multiple versions of the same package**

```
sudo rpm -e --nodeps `dnf repoquery --installed --queryformat '%{name}-%{epoch}:%{version}-%{release}.%{arch} %{from_repo}' | grep -i "reponame" | awk '{print $1}'`
```